# why does where not exists expression does not give correct output

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables :

**Table:#a**

id | name
10 |  a
20 |  b
30 |  c
40 |  d
50 |  e

**Table:#b**

id | name

10 |  a

30 |  a

50 |  a

I want all the #a table Id which are not present in #b

The following query works :

```
select * from #a as a
where  not exists(select * from #b as b where a.id = b.id)
```

But I am not able to understand why the below query does not work

```
select * from #a as a
where exists(select * from #b as b where a.id <> b.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does where not exists expression does not give correct output

The first query does yield the right result : select all records from A where doesnt have appropriate match in B

But the second one is logically different.

Looking at :

```
;with A(id,name) as 
(
select 10,'a' UNION ALL
select 20,'b' UNION ALL
select 30,'c' UNION ALL
select 40,'d' UNION ALL
select 50,'e' 

) ,B(id,name) as 
(
select 10,'a' UNION ALL
select 30,'a' UNION ALL
select 50,'a' 

)   

select * from a as a
where exists(select * from b as b where a.id <> b.id)
```

For each record from `a`, show that record if  exists records from `b` with *non-matched* id.

So for `10,a` (in `a`) **there ARE(!)** records from `B` where `id` is not `10` , hence  it **does** YIELDS `10,a` (from `a`)!

Now - do you see the problem ?